# remove annoying "NA" entries from my R data (rm.na=TRUE not working!)

Tags: r, tapply

I have some data I'm trying to analyze. I have two variables - one is a yes or no type question, the other has many possible answers (but categorical - like "not at all, a bit, neutral, lots, 100%").

I want to use tapply to calculate the proportion. I don't know how to do that. I know how to calculate mean, like this:

```
tapply(dataset$variable1, dataset$variable2, mean)
```

Anyways, I don't know how to get proportion instead of mean like this, but besides that, when I do try to get the mean, I get: 
 0  1 
NA NA 
Because my data obviously has NA answers in it. I tried adding the "rm.na=TRUE" value, but that didn't fix it. So how do I get rid of these NA's? Or is there another way I could calculate proportions like that? (calculate: what proportion of people who anwered yes to question variable 1 also answered 3 to question variable 2?)

Comment: How about using `na.rm` instead of `rm.na`? Here's an example that works with `na.rm=TRUE`, but not without: `tapply(c(NA, rnorm(99)), sample(1:3, 100, replace=T), mean, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Duh! I'm such a noob! Thanks, I just got their order wrong! Thank you! (I don't even know how to upvote your comment, goddamit LOL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u need to use tapply(na.omit(dataset$variable1), na.omit(dataset$variable2), mean)

```
DF <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(0, 10, NA))
DF
```

```
  x  y
1 1  0
2 2 10
3 3 NA
```

```
na.omit(DF)
```

```
  x  y
1 1  0
2 2 10
```